# How can I generate a list of all possible permutations in range

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, permutation, python-itertools

I would like to generate words list in a specific way. I would like to find all permutations for my variable l='EDCMI' not only for 5 characters but for 4 characters, 3 characters etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a *nested* `for` loop and remember to add 1 to your range argument to include permutations the same length as your input string:

```
from itertools import permutations

s = 'EDCMI'

for i in range(len(s) + 1):
    for p in permutations(s, i):
        print(''.join(p))
```

Comment: you have to start the range of your outer loop at 1 if you don't want the empty element `''`